# Vue-cli 3.0, passing Options to Pre-Processor Loaders (multiple files)

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

I've this config in `vue.config.js`, from [official documentation](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/docs/css.md)

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false,
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: fs.readFileSync('src/sass/variables.sass', 'utf-8')
      }
    }
  }
};
```

How it can be, if i want pass multiple files, ex. `src/sass/mixin.sass`?

One of solution is to create one file named ex. `main.sass`

```
@import variables
@import mixin
```

Any other solutions, using `vue.config.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` takes a string as argument, not a file (or a list of files).

So, in order to get input from multiple files, you would have to load them individually and join their content.

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false,
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: ['src/sass/variables.sass', 'src/sass/mixin.sass']
                            .map(fileName => fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'utf-8')).join('\n')
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Or create a helper function, for readability:

```
const fs = require('fs');

function loadFiles(files) {
  return files.map(fileName => fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'utf-8')).join('\n')
}

module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false,
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: loadFiles(['src/sass/variables.sass', 'src/sass/mixin.sass'])

      }
    }
  }
};
```